# Serve all pages over https not just homepage

Tags: htaccess, https, mod-rewrite

I want to serve all of my website pages over https, but currently my htaccess only serves the homepage over https.

This is the code I have in my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

If you go to the following page it is served still over http: 
http://www.coerll.utexas.edu/spintx/video/1506

But the homepage is served over https:
http://www.coerll.utexas.edu/spintx/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have put the directives in the wrong place in your `.htaccess` file. The HTTP to HTTPS redirect needs to go near the top, before any other rewrites.

The nature of your URLs suggest you are using a front-controller type pattern and rewriting requests to a common script. However, the "homepage" does not need to be rewritten (since mod_dir will issue an internal subrequest for the directory index). If you place the mod_rewrite redirect *after* the front-controller then all but the homepage will be redirected.

**UPDATE:** From discussion in comments, there are no other directives in `.htaccess` and it would seem the website is driven with directives in the main server config (not accessible to the OP). Furthermore, it seems the `.htaccess` file (located in the `/spintx` subdirectory) is bypassed entirely for all requests, other than the homepage! Access to the server config is probably required in order to diagnose this further and implement an Apache HTTP to HTTPS redirect.

Implementing the HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the web application itself (Drupal 7) would be an alternative.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> </IfModule>
> ```

These directives are generally OK for most servers. You don't really need the `<IfModule>` wrapper, unless you are planning on copying these same directives to multiple servers where mod_rewrite might not be installed.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^(.*)$` can be simplified to just `^` since the captured subpattern is not being used in the *substitution* (you are using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead).

Comment: That is the only mod_rewrite code in my htaccess file. I don't know if there are other htaccess directives on the server, since I am not maintaining the server. So could this front-controller be somewhere else on the server?

Comment: The "front-controller" could be in the main server config / virtual host. If it is then you won't be able to change this behaviour in `.htaccess`. Do you not control these aspects of the website? Where exactly in the `.htaccess` file located? Do you have other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? "other htaccess directives on the server" - they are "Apache directives", `.htaccess` is just a _context_ in which they can be used.

Comment: I don't control the server config/virtual host. My `.htaccess` file is located in the root folder of my website. I have the mod_rewrite issue with several websites that are hosted on that server, but my htaccess websites do work. In one instance I successfully increased the php_value memory_limit.

Comment: And where is the "root folder of your website"? Is this in the `/spintx` subdirectory? How are the URLs being routed?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Try (temporarily) adding`RewriteOptions IgnoreInherit` before your existing directives in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: URLs are routed by our server team.

Comment: `RewriteOptions IgnoreInherit` is added inside the existing mod_rewrite after `RewriteEngine on` then followed by `RewriteCond ...`?

Comment: Yes. You can add it at the top of the file, it doesn't matter. (What do you mean "URLs are routed by our server team"?)

Comment: Did that change anything?

Comment: When I added `RewriteOptions IgnoreInherit` to my `.htaccess` file, I got an `Internal Server Error` on the homepage. There was no error on any of the subpages, but they were also not served over `https`.

Comment: What version of Apache are you on? Can you check your server's error log for the details of that error? If there was no "Internal Server Error" for subpages then that would seem to imply that the `.htaccess` (or mod_rewrite) was completely bypassed for such requests?! Try adding some "random nonsense" to the start of the `.htaccess` file and repeat the test: homepage vs subpages.

Comment: Apache 2.2.15. Yes there is no server error for subpages. I did add something at the start of the `.htaccess` and had again a server error for the homepage and no server error for the subpages. So I guess you are right, the server team here is blocking my `.htaccess` file for the subpages. I will have to contact them again to see why this is the case. I just wanted to double check that my directive code was correct. But I guess that is the case. Thanks for your help in figuring out this strange issue.

Comment: If you are still on Apache 2.2 then that explains the server error when using `RewriteOptions IgnoreInherit` (requires Apache 2.4.8+). Yes, it would seem you will need to contact the "server team" to know what is going on here. Your redirect directive looks OK. Alternatively, you could implement this redirect within your web application (Drupal 7?) instead? I've updated my answer.